# CSS: Use number of a class/id as value for another class/id

Tags: html, css

I have created a "CSS-only" Website that uses only CSS/HTML/PHP, with a CSS Menu, dynamic loading content (images) and a CSS Magnifier. I don´t want to use Javascript/jQuery or Cookies and the Website works perfectly so far. The layout was really hard to adjust to fit correctly to all browsers but finally I got the Apple-InternetExplorer (Safari) working too.

For the menu I used the ["Checkbox Hack"](https://css-tricks.com/the-checkbox-hack/). But instead of checkboxes I´m using radio-buttons to display only one content-page. That looks like this:

```
<!-- 
We need these input-fields to trigger display:block on another element 
The radio-buttons must use the same "name" to jump between different content-pages. 
(only 1 Radio-Button can be active)
-->
<input type="radio" id="radioactive-1" name="radioactive">
<input type="radio" id="radioactive-2" name="radioactive">

<!-- This simple menu triggers the radio-button with the id (for=id) -->
<label for="radioactive-1">Menu-Entry 1</label>
<label for="radioactive-2">Menu-Entry 2</label>

<!-- Heres the content to display, but it is set to display: none; 
so the content only gets displayed if the correct radio-button is active -->
<div id='content-wrapper'>
    <div id='not-radioactive-1' style='display:none;'></div>
    <div id='not-radioactive-2' style='display:none;'></div>
</div>
```

That markup was shortened, but I think its clear enough. Now we need the CSS which is important to get this to work:

```
input[id="radioactive-1"]:checked ~ #content-wrapper #not-radioactive-1 {
    display:block!important;
}
input[id="radioactive-2"]:checked ~ #content-wrapper #not-radioactive-2 {
    display:block!important;
}
```

You can see that these CSS-Declarations can get very long and I´m triggering multiple styles to different elements with one click. The code for the menu is ~20 KB and thats massive.(50% the size of my CSS-File)

**Now my question: Is there any way to get the number of the class for the input field to use it for the content class?**

Example:

```
input[id="radioactive-$value"]:checked ~ #not-radioactive-$value
```

I know one way to ignore the number and use all id´s including a defined string.

Example:

```
input[id^="radioactive-"]:checked
```

I also know that I can use PHP and just do a loop but in the end the CSS have the same size, because the whole code gets echoed. I´m searching for a CSS-only solution if this is possible. I only want to shorten my code and speed up page-loading.

Comment: I know you're probably reluctant to alter (and probably won't) but using hacks and tricks to avoid js should be kept to a minimum. Trust me, using JS would make your website more efficient as well as shorter and easier to maintain in the future. I'm not saying to scrap what you have and restart, but what can be done with JS allows you to clean up and shorten CSS to what it should be.

Comment: The simple answer is "NO"...this is the type of thing JS was written for. I echo the comments of @jbutler483

Comment: I´m understanding what you mean, but yes there´s no way I´m using JS if there is no way to build it with CSS. (and there is) The so called hack (in my opinion it isn´t) works like a charm for all modern browsers and since IE9 I think. (I have to test it) Everything is as performant as with JS and can´t be blocked by any browser-extension. At first view the code is difficult to understand, sure! But that page is for personal purposes and I don´t have to care about a big range of users, only a few. Thanks for your comment but that isn´t the solution I´m searching for.

Comment: You could use a CSS preprocessor like SASS to handle the grunt work instead of writing it all out manually, however, you will still end up with the same CSS in the end so it won't help in reducing the file size.

Comment: @HiddenHobbes Good point, but you´re right. I also thought about compressing the css, but the file only gets 5% smaller and I have to do this as a final step. Another way is to using gzip or cacheing the css-file, but this isn´t a real solution to my current problem.

Comment: You should better use class names for styling the elements. My personal rule is, that I only use ID's for label-input relation and anchor targets (e.g. `<h2 id="my-fancy-headline">`). And avoid inline styles. Following those simple rules will save you a lot of pain.

Comment: **Given the constraints you are imposing** I do not see a "solution" that you would accept. Basically, you've made your bed so you'll have to lie in it and put the extra work in.

Comment: @feeela I´m using classes and this was only an example for stackoverflow. I can´t remember why I´m using the display:; as inline style.

Comment: @Paulie_D I got it. So the only real "solution" is what feeela & user3687099 mentioned, right? Not for me, but in general I think.

Comment: Yes, I think so Either restructure the HTML or use a tiny bit of JS to solve the issue. It's a choice of course, but you're the only one who can make it.

Comment: @Paulie_D Thanks for your answer. I can´t find another way on my own and you guys are right. Anyway I will use this code as it is and try to compress the css as much as I can. 0.5s time to completely load the page is okay I think.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can do that without relying on those numbers by inserting the radio buttons directly before each section:

HTML:

```
<div id="content-wrapper">
    <input type="radio" id="radioactive-1" name="radioactive">
    <div class="content"></div>

    <input type="radio" id="radioactive-2" name="radioactive">
    <div class="content"></div>
</div>
```

CSS:

```
.content {
    display: none;
}

input[name="radioactive"]:checked + .content {
    display: block;
}
```

It doesn't matter where the labels are, as long as the `for` attributes matches to some input.

Comment: But it matters where the input-fields are. I have to insert them directly after body to access every element. If you insert them like you mentioned you can´t access elements outside #content-wrapper. It´s impossible to change my markup to your example, that was one of my first trys and believe me you get serious problems with your layout. €dit:  As example I have to change the color of active menu-buttons with one click.

Comment: @Pandora Well, in that case you really should use JS…

Comment: You posted the correct answer first and now I´m sure this is the only right answer. No is wrong but your solution works in general, so I will mark it as top answer.

Answer (score 1):

One solution is that you can use the PHP loop in the HTML file and using the loop, print following piece of code,

```html
<div id='content-wrapper'>
    <input type="radio" id="radioactive-1" name="radioactive">
    <label for="radioactive-1">Menu-Entry 1</label>
    <div id='not-radioactive-1' style='display:none;'></div>

    <input type="radio" id="radioactive-2" name="radioactive">
    <label for="radioactive-2">Menu-Entry 2</label>
    <div id='not-radioactive-2' style='display:none;'></div>
</div>
```

And the CSS file would have the following,

```css
input[type="radio"]:checked ~ div {
    display:block!important;
}
```

Comment: Same as feeela mentioned, this won´t work for me. Please read my comment under his answer.

Comment: Another possible solution can be assigning the respective div id's to the radio buttons itself as data-* attributes and using `attr()` defined for CSS,

Read the Mozilla documentation, 
https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/attr
The problem is that it's not supported even by some of the major browsers.

Comment: Nice idea ... Is this the correct one [Can I use attr](http://caniuse.com/#feat=css-sel2)? €dit: Nope, this is another one. Do you know a link where I can check the compatibility? (MSDN lists only e.g. Chrome 2.0.

Comment: Can´t edit my comment. Misunderstood the compatibility list. I try to make a fiddle. Maybe it works this way and this is a real solution.

Comment: Ok I created a fiddle but had no idea of how to use this data attribute. Have a look here: [Fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/7dkak4ag/)

Comment: I give up. Logically one can target exactly one input-field with a label. I was able to half the size of the code by using another selector (~*) to target id´s anywhere in the body and after I customized the code of the loaded content. Another approach with :target also can´t target/check more than one element or customize display and so on. Nice idea but this also won´t work for me.

Comment: I will try to find another possible CSS hack...;)

Comment: I posted the code I want to shorten to this [Fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/aLcosmth/). Maybe you find find or see a way, I have no more ideas.